# Android; change the background of a layout/screen by clicking a button

Tags: android, layout, button

So I have several buttons, and I want the background of an app screen to change depending on which button I click. So if I click a button with the writing "blue", the background changes to a specified image which I've created in the res folder. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's my answer which is correct, not him lol , you are accepted the worong answer men

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change image by using code

```
public void onClick(View v) {
if(v==ButtonName)
ButtonName.setImageResource(R.drawable.ImageName); 
}
```

or using XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/login_selected" /> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/login_mouse_over" /> <!-- focused -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/login" /> <!-- default -->
```

OnClick just add this code

```
ButtonName.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ImageName))
```

Even if you want me background drawable, here it is:

```
android:background="@drawable/ImageName"
```

Now, you can compound them

Comment: he want to change the background of the screen , and not of the Button :)

Comment: look at my answer carefully dude :)

Comment: I'll try it when I get home, thanks for the quick response :)

Comment: Actually I've just wrote exact answer, at the last pharagraph:
`ButtonName.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ImageName));`

Comment: look at your answer , he want to change the background of the app screen and not of the button clicked, soo you should change the background of the parent Layout of the activity , and not the one of the button :)

Comment: Don't you know background is also a drawable. He can just add `android:background="@drawable/ImageName">`.

Comment: I've just wanted him to comprehend the logic within

Comment: and one more thing , there is no need to the selector here , he did'nt say that he want to change the background of the button when the button is selected ,or pressed ...etc, all what you need in your answer , is to  get the Root Layout of the activity , and Change its background  with the same logic that you've posted and without selector =)

Comment: I know how to change the background image using android:background="@drawable/ImageName", but I want it to be changed when the user clicks a certain button.

Comment: @Houcine Do you imply that: "enough is as good as a feast"? :). Don't be stern that much..

Comment: @user565460 I explain to you how to assign a drawable to a button. I think you can combine them on your own. If I wrote the whole code, it would not have been beneficial for you :)

Comment: im just saying that in your answer , you are not answering the question of @user565460 :), see my answer

Comment: @Houcine this won't be good for him, he could find the required information by small-scale searching. If you write the whole code, I would be able to say: the question is not constructive. Got that right??

Comment: you are out of subject my friend , my first comment on your answer is about that he want to change the background of the app screen and not of the button , the meaning is you should read the question before answering , that's all . take it easy like this ;)

Answer (score 3):

in your `onCreate()` Method get your `Views` like this :

```
rootLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
btnBlue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBlue);
btnRed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRed);
btnGreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGreen);
```

and set the `onClickListener` on all buttons like this :

```
btnRed.setOnClickListener(this);
btnGreen.setOnClickListener(this);
btnBlue.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and override the method `onClick()` like this :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
  Drawable background = null;
  switch(v.getId()){
     case R.id.btnBlue :drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imageBlue); break;
     case R.id.btnRed : drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imageRed); break;
     case R.id.btnGreen : drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imageGreen); break;
   }
rootLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
}
```